TextFields in a Form are not showing
I've been trying to make a filter list for a furniture selling company and can't seem to make it work.
Everything is showing on this page except my two TextFields and I can't understand why.
This is my code:
import SwiftUI

struct FilterView: View {
        @Environment(\.themeColor) var themeColor: Color

    @Binding var presentSideMenu: Bool
    @Binding var showResearch: Bool
    
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    @State var searchprixMin: Int = 0
    @State var searchprixMax: Int = 0
    @State private var selectedProduct: Produit?
    @State private var productViewShow = false
    
//  @State private var showingFilter = false

    let produits: [Produit] = [
        Produit(id: "1", name: "Billy Blanc Bibliothèque", image: ["BillyBlancBibliothèque", "BillyBlancBibliothèque2", "BillyBlancBibliothèque3"], description: "Bibliothèque Blanche", price: 80, stock: true),
        Produit(id: "2", name: "Billy Bibliothèque Corner", image: ["BillyCorner", "BillyCorner2", "BillyCorner3"], description: "Bibliothèque Blanche d'angle", price: 120, stock: true),
        Produit(id: "3", name: "Friheten Convertible Sofa Skiftebo DarkGrey", image: ["FrihetenConvertibleSofaSkifteboDarkGrey", "FrihetenConvertibleSofaSkifteboDarkGrey2", "FrihetenConvertibleSofaSkifteboDarkGrey3"], description: "Canapé d'angle Gris foncé", price: 2000, stock: true),
    ]
    
    

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                Form {
                    TextField("Prix min €", value: $searchprixMin, format: .number)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                    TextField("Prix max €", value: $searchprixMax, format: .number)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                }
                ForEach(filteredProduct) { produit in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedProduct = produit
                        productViewShow = true
                    }) {
                        ProduitCard(produit: produit, pictureHeight: 300)
                            .padding([.leading, .top, .trailing])
                    } //: Button
                }
                .navigationTitle("Search")
                .searchable(text: $searchText)
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $productViewShow) {
                if selectedProduct != nil {
                    ProductView(presentSideMenu: $presentSideMenu, showResearch: $showResearch, produit: selectedProduct!)
                } else {
                    ParamsView(presentSideMenu: $presentSideMenu, showResearch: $showResearch)
                }
            }
            .background(themeColor)
        }
    }
    
    var filteredProduct: [Produit] {
//      guard !searchText.isEmpty else { return produits }
//      return produits.filter { produit in
//          produit.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
//      }
        
        return produits.filter { produit in
            let isMatchingText = searchText.isEmpty || produit.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            let isMatchingPriceRange = (searchprixMin == 0 || produit.price >= searchprixMin) && (searchprixMax == 0 || produit.price <= searchprixMax)
            
            return isMatchingText && isMatchingPriceRange
        }
        
    }
}

I've tried to put some foregroundcolor to a bright yellow or even to comment my ForEach but nothing seems to work.

Replace Form with VStack but shouldn't the TextField's be above the scroll view?

With the TextField above the scrollview it indeed works better, Thanks! But now i'm facing another issue, because it's outside the scrollview it never disappear... But i would like if I could scroll to see the filtered list that's under it. But anyway at least I have something so thanks

You have to five the Form a size.
